Rigorous proof of ASA Congruence rule
Using Hilbert's axioms of geometry how can we prove with rigor that the angle-side-angle congruence rule is true?
Most of the proofs I have seen of this seem to rely on the diagram and follow this procedure:

Let there be triangles $\overset{\triangle}{ABC}$ and $\overset{\triangle}{DEF}$, with $\angle ABC = \angle DEF$, $\angle ACB = \angle DFE$ and $\overline{BC} = \overline{EF}$.
If $\overline{AB} = \overline{DE}$, then obviously the triangles will be congruent by the side-angle-side criterion. Assume that $\overline{AB} \neq \overline{DE}$ and that $\overline{AB} \gt \overline{DE}$.
Since $\overline{AB} \gt \overline{DE}$ there is a point $P$ on side $\overline{AB}$ such that $\overline{BP} = \overline{DE}$.
Then, by SAS,  we will have that $\overset{\triangle}{BPC}=\overset{\triangle}{DEF}$ and consequently that $\angle BCP = \angle DFE$.
But we know that $\angle ACB = \angle DFE$, and therefore we conclude that $\angle ACB = \angle BCP$.
This is impossible since $P$ is between $A$ and $C$, which means that it is in the interior of angle $\angle ACB$ and therefore the angles cannot be equal.

My problem with this line of reasoning is in the last line. It seems like an obvious fact. However I can't figure out how it can be proven from first principles. I tried using the crossbar theorem but it leads nowhere.

To be clear, your question is why P must lie in the interior of angle ACB? Or is it that P lying in the interior implies the two angles are not equal? Or both?

I am confused about the latter.

Here's step 6 taken from Hilbert's book: "This, however, is impossible, since, by axiom IV, 4, an angle can be laid off in one and only one way on a given side of a given half-ray of a plane. From this contradiction the theorem follows". Looks quite clear to me.

I believe start of the 6th step should state that $P$ is between $A$ and $B$.
I'm taking Hilbert's Axioms of Geometry from this source. On page 9 it states:

Using this axiom in our particular case, we can let $O'=O=C $ and $A'=B$. Then, this axiom implies that there is a unique ray $r(C,B')$ on $A$'s side of $CB$ such that $\angle BCA \cong \angle BCB'$, and moreover that $r(C,B')=r(C,A)$.
In our case, it's clear that $P$ is on $A$'s side of $\overline{CB}$ since ${CB}$ and ${AP}$ don't intersect*. Moreover, Step 5 shows the ray $r(C,P)$ has the property that $\angle BCA \cong \angle BCP$, and thus $r(C,P)=r(C,A)$. Therefore, $A,P,$ and $C$ are collinear. But note that of course, $A,B,P$ are collinear, and thus all four points $A$, $B$, $C$, and $P$ are collinear. But this contradicts the fact that $A,B,$ and $C$ form a triangle. So your assumption in Step 2 must have been mistaken, and thus ${AB}={DE}$, and the triangles are congruent by SAS.
*Here I explain why ${CB}$ and ${AP}$ don't intersect. Note that $\overline{CB}\cap \overline{AP} = \overline{CB}\cap \overline{AB} = \{B\}$. So in order for segments ${CB}$ and ${AP}$ to intersect, they would have to intersect at $B$. But $P$ is between $A$ and $B$, so $B$ is not on the segment ${AP}$.
